# What is the function of inductors in series between the terminals and the brushes of a DC motor?

Tags: motor, electric

I'm repairing (hopefully) a 12 V DC motor (Johnson Electric HC971(2)LG-101).

The motor has a coil in the motor cap between each terminal and the corresponding brush - two coils (inductors) one on each side of the armature electrically speaking. It also has what I think is a resistor on one side and what I think is a (broken) capacitor between the two terminals.

What is the function of the two inductors in series between the terminals and brushes?

I'm sure this info it's out there somewhere but I haven't found it online after several days of searching.

Answer (score 1):

Likely the series induction prevent higher frequencies from making it back from the motor to the power supply. The inductors looks like an open circuit to higher frequencies.

A parallel capacitor can also help as it shorts the higher frequencies preventing them from getting back to the power supply.

Comment: Sounds like your motor has field windings and an armature winding, and no permanent magnets. Do you have a wiring diagram?

Answer (score 0):

those inductors is to block back ac voltage from going back to the DC power source

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* user26983. Thanks for your answer but we are looking for comprehensive answers that provide some explanation and context. Very short answers cannot do this, so please edit your answer to explain why it is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed. See [answer] for more info.